# Firebase Storage - Image preview is permenantly loading

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I've started working with firebase storage and firebase functions recently. Right now I've been developing file upload from functions to storage .

I've got it working (upload is done and file appears on the storage section), yet, the image, stays like this forever (loading forever on the right side):

[image: Print screen from firebase storage]

I though that it was an error from my code. Yet, if I open Google Cloud Platform - Storage, the image appears and I can open it and preview it.

In firebase storage, if I open the image (select on it and click open), it returns the following url: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/undefined

What may I been doing wrong? Here's the code I'm using:

```html
function uploadImage() {
    const newImageData = "data:image/png;base64,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"

    var mimeTypes = require('mimetypes');
    var image = newImageData,
        mimeType = image.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/)![1],
        fileName = 'test.' + mimeTypes.detectExtension(mimeType),
        base64EncodedImageString = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''),
        imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64EncodedImageString, 'base64');

    // Instantiate the GCP Storage instance
    const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const googleCloudStorage = new Storage(firebaseSettings);
    const bucket = googleCloudStorage.bucket('projectID.appspot.com');


    var file = bucket.file(fileName);
    return file.save(imageBuffer, {
        metadata: { contentType: mimeType, cacheControl: "public, max-age=300" },
        public: true,
        validation: 'md5'
    }, function (error: any) {

        if (error) {
            throw 'error';
        }

        return "https://storage.googleapis.com/share-expanses-dcc9f.appspot.com/" + fileName;
    });
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: If the Firebase console doesn't appear to work correctly, or you are seeing some errors, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, didn't though about it being a Firebase problem. Already have contacted, waiting for response (will update post after)

Comment: @C.Gadd just added an new answer to this problem with their response. I haven't been able to test it meanwhile. If you are capable of fixing it, let us know about it :) I'll do the same

Answer (score 3):

Haven't been able to test the solution given by Firebase, but here's the transcript of the response:

> The problem that you are facing could be because of two reasons. The
>   first one is how you are uploading the files, via the Firebase
>   Console, using any Admin SDK, or via the gsutil command. If using the
>   Admin SDK option, the problem is a known issue where the required
>   metadata doesn’t exist, fortunately there is a workaround, you can try
>   this [script](https://gist.github.com/torresalmonte/7bd888ff0b27fd741faf29d473ecb079) to solve this issue.
>
> Now, the second one is related to the [network if you are using](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4913)
>   comcast, please, try on a different network to see if this issue is
>   related to that.

Answer (score 2):

When you save an image to firebase, you need to provide an access token in metadata : `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens`. It has to be an `uuid`.

More info can be found here : https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens

```js
const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid")

function uploadImage() {
    const newImageData = "data:image/png;base64,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"

    var mimeTypes = require('mimetypes');
    var image = newImageData,
        mimeType = image.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/)![1],
        fileName = 'test.' + mimeTypes.detectExtension(mimeType),
        base64EncodedImageString = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''),
        imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64EncodedImageString, 'base64');

    // Instantiate the GCP Storage instance
    const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const googleCloudStorage = new Storage(firebaseSettings);
    const bucket = googleCloudStorage.bucket('projectID.appspot.com');


    var file = bucket.file(fileName);
    return file.save(imageBuffer, {
        metadata: { 
          contentType: mimeType,
          cacheControl: "public,
          max-age=300",
          // THIS IS THE LINE YOU NEED TO ADD
          firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid(),
        },
        public: true,
        validation: 'md5'
    }, function (error: any) {

        if (error) {
            throw 'error';
        }

        return "https://storage.googleapis.com/share-expanses-dcc9f.appspot.com/" + fileName;
    });
}
```

After that you'll need to click on "Create access token"

[image]

Comment: You need to wrap the `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` in a `metadata` object for it to work

Answer (score 2):

@jean-smaug answer is almost complete. Based on the page he linked (https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens), the only missing thing is to wrap the `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` property inside a `metadata` object. I've just tested it and it's working fine  No need to create access token afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added metadata while uploading and it loading as it showed in image but when I'm refresh page after 3 min  I found that it upload correctly  , so as **Cafn** explain if it not matter of metadata you should wait until it loaded

```
  $uploadedObject=$bucket->upload($imageFile, [
            'name' => 'Image_Name',
            "metadata" => [  "contentType"=> 'image/png'],
        ]);
```